# What is Kubra talking about at the end of S03E08?

Tags: dialogue, orange-is-the-new-black

Near the end of *Orange is the New Black* S03E08 Kubra says

> When a fucker gets so lazy he no longer bothers to buy burners to make calls on, that is too fucking human?

What does that line mean?

Comment: when you're lazy, paranoia runs out, ways you did to protect yourself, seems unnecessary and you'll be careless. choosing easier way is what humans would do if they have no other reason not to. in this case, your need to be protected, steps you'd take if you needed are not needed now. so you'd go for the natural way of choosing the easy way

Comment: Is there a specific part which is unclear?

Comment: @MattHolland burners to make calls on?

Answer (score 1):

A burner is a disposable throwaway prepaid cellphone.
[enter link description here](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=burner)

So basically Kubra was upset that his employee was using a regular cellphone or some other method to conduct calls and/or communications because of the added privacy of a prepaid cellular device.